# pyplot auto-adjust axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an easy way to get pyplot to treat calls to `text()` or `annotate()` as if they were "data", so that it automatically expanded the axis limits to include the text within the plot boundaries (i.e., not in the margin)?

```
# this creates a barplot with a significance bracket
# but the p-value above the bracket overlaps the plot title
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
b = plt.bar((0, 1), (2, 3), yerr=(0.1, 0.2))
bracket = [[[0.4, 0.4], [2.5, 3.8]],
           [[0.4, 1.4], [3.8, 3.8]],
           [[1.4, 1.4], [3.4, 3.8]]]
for x, y in bracket:
    p.plot(x, y, 'k')
txt = p.text(0.9, 4.0, 'p < 0.001', ha='center')
plt.title('A significant MWE')
```

[image: matplotlib barplot with significance bracket]

My current workaround involves creating the text, calling `draw()`, getting the text's `bbox_patch` extents, transforming those extents to data coordinates, and manually changing the `ybound` of the axes object to something bigger than the transformed upper extent. This seems rather roundabout to me, and I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my workaround. Inelegant, but functional. If anyone has a better way, I'd still love to hear it.

```
txt.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='w', alpha=0, boxstyle='round, pad=1'))
plt.draw()
txtbb = txt.get_bbox_patch().get_window_extent()
ymax = p.transData.inverted().transform(txtbb).ravel()[-1]
ybnd = p.get_ybound()
if ymax > ybnd[-1]:
    p.set_ybound(ybnd[0], ymax)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib barplot with adjusted axis limits]